# Are M.A.S.K fighting 'all the time' or 'overtime'?

Tags: cartoon, mobile-armored-strike-kommand

Growing up, watching M.A.S.K myself and my brother would always hear in the intro song:

> Masked crusaders, working overtime! Fighting crime!

I guess we assumed that all their work for M.A.S.K. was outside of their day job, which made it overtime? Regardless, we'd joke they weren't paid enough.

However on recently looking for the lyrics to the song I got [conflicting](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/mask-ost-mask-intro-lyrics.html) [results](https://www.smule.com/song/sung-by-noam-kaniel-composed-by-shuki-levi-m-a-s-k-english-80s-cartoon-theme-karaoke-lyrics/4139673_4139673/arrangement) back from my search.

Listening to the intro on YouTube hasn't helped, as I keep hearing 'overtime'; [listen](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Hh11NDMHVl0) for yourself.

Which is it?

Comment: I'm 99% certain it's overtime.

Comment: @Valorum then maybe the lyrics I linked to that said "all the time" are the ones that are wrong?

Comment: I believe that's the case. It's an interestingly hard one to prove definitely, unlike the lyrics (for example) for Jayce or Ninja Turtles, where we have the lyrics on inlay cards from the OST cassettes

Comment: Hmm. One of the recent fan-comics was titled "*fighting overtime*". I wouldn't consider that good evidence though.

Comment: I would, but I'm probably still going to reserve the check mark for irrefutable confirmation from somebody involved in the song or show.

Comment: I've sent the usual tweets and emails to the song's writers.

Answer (score 11):

I found quotes posted on an Italian-language message board in 2014, which suggest that the correct lyrics are "working overtime".

The quotes were posted in English, alongside translations in Italian, which I've removed from the block quote below.

> YouTube User: Can someone clear up whether it is "Masquerades" or "Masked Charades". It's so hard to actually hear it, I've listened to it quite a few times and can't tell for certain.
>
> Larry Leon: The lyrics are "Masked Charades". This song was a bit hard to enunciate due to the wordy nature and the tempo.
>
> YouTube User: What's the lyric where it goes "Secret raider who will neutralise to the day arrives" or something like that?
>
> Larry Leon: "Secret raiders, who will neutralize, as soon as they arrive (at the site)". If I recall...I didn't sing the word "as", there was no room to fit that in. It didn't "sing" well.
>
> YouTube User: Is the line Masked Crusaders "working overtime" or "working all the time"? I have always heard "overtime", and I can't imagine it being anything else, but a lot of people are pretty sure it's not...
>
> **Larry Leon: You are correct, the lyrics are "working overtime".**
>
> <sub>[The TV-Pedia forum - Sigle Saban Records: Jayce and MASK - page 2](http://www.tv-pedia.com/zapzaptv/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5268&start=15)</sub>

According to 'BubbleGum TV' -- the forum user who posted these quotes -- they were made by the vocalist of the English-language version of the M.A.S.K. theme song, [Larry Leon](https://www.discogs.com/artist/3512985-Larry-Leon), on his YouTube channel. The quote directly below was originally posted in Italian, and I used the Google Chrome language translator to convert it to English.

> BubbleGum TV: Last week Larry Leon posted a series of comments on YouTube claiming to be the true interpreter of MASK's original English-language theme song, proving somewhat displeased that his interpretation was often mistakenly attributed to Noam Kaniel ( who instead interpreted the French version of the theme song of MASK with Nick Carr), highlighting the vocal differences between him and Kaniel himself. Among the other works that he has declared to have done in his musical career, he did not mention other acronyms, so he is not the interpreter of the original English theme song of "Jayce, the Knight of Space".
>
> <sub>[The TV-Pedia forum - Sigle Saban Records: Jayce and MASK - page 1](http://www.tv-pedia.com/zapzaptv/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5268)</sub>

The discussion thread I lifted these quotes from also features many other quotes attributed to Leon, including this explanation of his experience working on the M.A.S.K. theme song.

> Larry Leon: The song M.A.S.K. was recorded at Haim's studio on Ventura Blvd. in Studio City. I was asked to show up at the studio at 7:00am which was a bit unusual. I generally like to be fully awake when I perform vocal tracks! I had never heard the song before ...and got familiar with it while the rough mix was being worked out. I ran through the song a few time to warm up and then sang a "keeper" vocal track. We took a break...grabbed a bite to eat and then I sang all of the background vocals (harmonies). Both Haim and Shuki were there participating in the production. The music track was completed before I showed up to sing the vocal track so....I have no idea what was used.
>
> <sub>[The TV-Pedia forum - Sigle Saban Records: Jayce and MASK - page 2](http://www.tv-pedia.com/zapzaptv/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5268&start=15)</sub>

Unfortunately, no link to the original source of these quotes was provided, and I couldn't find a YouTube account obviously belonging to the correct Larry Leon, although it's entirely possible that he could've deleted such an account during the seven years which have passed since these quotes were originally posted.

I did find a video interview with Leon, where he discusses his experience working on the M.A.S.K. theme song.

Below is a partial transcript of what Leon said in this video interview, and it closely corresponds to the quote lifted from the Italian message board. (The wording isn't identical, since the quote just above apparently came from a YouTube comments section originally, rather than this video interview, but the experience described by Leon is essentially the same in both cases.)

> Larry Leon: I was in a band with Ricky Phillips from The Babys and some other heavy hitters. [...] Rick's girlfriend, a girl named Teresa -- really nice person -- she worked at Haim Saban studio on Ventura Boulevard in Studio City, and I guess they were probably discussing "Who can we get for this?" She had heard a lot of stuff that we were doing at that time, and said "I know a guy." And that's basically it. So she called me up and said "Hey, wanna go do a session tomorrow and sing something? There's a little bit of money in it for you, and if they end up using it, there's some little bit more." And I said "Yeah, okay." I didn't have a car back in the day then, so she ended up picking me up at like six o'clock in the morning. Which is just unheard of. I mean, I never did anything at six in the morning back then, except maybe go to sleep. So to actually go to a studio to record, I mean, that was just ridiculous. But she picked me up, she took me down there, and we kind of started working, real early.
>
> Bill Faries: So, for those who don't really understand like how a recording session works and things like that, how long did it take for you to do the track? Was it a one-and-done thing? Was it a span of time? How did it go that way?
>
> Larry Leon: Usually something like that, doing a vocal like that, I mean it can take a while. It depends, I mean I didn't know the song, I had never heard the thing before I walked in there. So me and Shuki Levy -- the guy that wrote the song, he was in the studio as well -- he was showing me kind of the vocal line, for the most part. And some parts he was being real particular about, wanting me to catch. So, before I'm in the actual recording booth, we're just in the control room, we're kinda going through all that. And after a while, I did a couple of takes, kind of warming my voice up, because like I said, by this time it's probably seven o'clock in the morning; you don't sing at that time in the morning. So we're kind of going through it a couple times, and then I did a take, and just kind of nailed it. And got everything pretty much right; there were a couple of little problems, here and there, maybe a little pitch problem on one word or something, tailing off or whatever. So we just fixed a couple of little problems. And then I think we ended up like taking a break, for breakfast; I don't know if we had breakfast, burritos, or bagels, whatever the hell. Somebody went out and grabbed something. We came back, we ate that, drank some coffee or whatever. And then worked on the background vocals. And that's all me singing the background vocals on there as well. Worked on the background vocals, and we were done and out of there by like noon. So it actually went fairly quick for something like that.
>
> <sub>YouTube video - Special Guest: Theme Vocalist, Larry Leon - S3E43 - [9:18](https://youtu.be/FzSh9BIe06k?t=558)</sub>

Leon also states in the video interview that he's posted comments online to correct people on the lyrics to the M.A.S.K. theme song (although he doesn't go into the specifics of those corrections within this video).

> Larry Leon: One thing with the lyrics that I've seen on some of these web pages is, some people are confused about the lyrics. Some people say "No, it's this word." And I'll pop in and go "No, it's actually this word." 'Cause, like I know it because I sang it. I mean, I can hear very plainly what I'm singing on the recording as well.
>
> <sub>YouTube video - Special Guest: Theme Vocalist, Larry Leon - S3E43 - [14:21](https://youtu.be/FzSh9BIe06k?t=861)</sub>

Comment: This is excellent... perhaps the only thing is to trim the 'corroborating' quotes, but I'm not sure if that's possible without losing the essence of them. Also, do those pages exist in the wayback machine?

Comment: I'll check the wayback machine, and update my answer if I find anything relevant.

Comment: I can just imagine Leon motioning with his hands, “lavoro straordinario,” “lavoro straordinario!”

Answer (score 8):

If you listen a little later in the extended version, we come across a second repetition of 'overtime' with much clearer diction.

> M.A.S.K
> Always riding hot on V.E.N.O.M's trail
> Come see the laser rays
> Fly away
>
> **Overtime**, fighting crime, fighting crime
> Illusion is the ultimate weapon
> M.A.S.K can use it right
> Every time, fighting crime

Obviously, this isn't *proof-positive* that the earlier use is 'overtime' rather than 'all the time', but the repetitive nature of the lyrics would strongly suggest that it is.